# Trying to get Prisma Extensions to be "Applied" the default import prisma from "@prisma/client"

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, prisma

using : Vue.js,typescript,prisma<4.16>

Hi I have create a couple of extensions im trying to apply them to the default prisma/client so that the other modules i have made work with the new extensions without having to go to them all amd make sure they importing the new prisma client with the extension included.

import { prismaJobExtension } from "../../prisma/extensions/jobs.extension.prisma";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

this.prismaClient = prismaJobExtension(prisma);